# how to get collapsible listview for android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have 3 list view named

activities-today, activities-this week, activities-this month.

I want to use collapsible list view format to show the lists. I've seen an example of collapsible list view using jquery mobile but i want to achieve this with java script,html and css. can anyone help me?[image]

I want something in this way as shown. Hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 

    <div data-role="header"> 
        <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1> 
    </div> 

    <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-filtertext="11:first:one"><a href="#">one</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="22:second:two"><a href="#">two</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="33:third:three"><a href="#">three</a></li>
<li data-filtertext="44:fourth:four"><a href="#">four</a></li>            
            </ul>

    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section B.</p>
    </div>

</div>


    </div>
</div>
​
```

Full source http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/UCDfU/

Comment: user is not wanting to do this with jquery-mobile. He wants only javascript-css-html;

Comment: @dhaval hi thanks for response i used jquery in my code to get collapsible listview as u said and i also felt that jquery is pretty easy to achieve this. I'm using <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.1.0.1.min.css"; whcih effecting my existing UI and if i remove this i'm not able to get view of collapsible listview. Is there any way to get collapsible listview without using jquery 1.0.1.css

Comment: may be you can just include the listview specific css from here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/css/structure/jquery.mobile.listview.css

Comment: check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/UCDfU/. includes limited css def from collapsible, listview and theme. You may still need to tweak/remove few things if required.

Answer (score 1):

I have set this jsfiddle for you, click on the title and the content will show up:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WPs6/38/)

Basically, with the onclick event of the title you decide wether to show or hide the content, and you change the title so it changes the +/- symbols. Of course this example only shows you how to implement the logic, but there are no nice looking styles applied to it.

the html:

```
<div class='collapsibleCont'>
<h3 id='collapsible1' class='collapsibleTitle' onclick="handleCollapsible('collapsible1')">+ title</h3>
<p  style="display:none" class='collapsibleContent'>helloooooooooooo</p>
</div>
```

the handleCollapsible(id) function:

```
function handleCollapsible(id){
var clickedTitle = document.getElementById(id);
var contentC = clickedTitle.parentNode.childNodes[1];
if(contentC.style.display=='none'){
        contentC.style.display = 'block';
        var mysplittedtitle = clickedTitle.innerHTML.split(" ");
        var newTitle = "- "+mysplittedtitle[1];
        clickedTitle.innerHTML =newTitle;


}else{
        contentC.style.display = 'none';
        var mysplittedtitle = clickedTitle.innerHTML.split(" ");
        var newTitle = "+ "+mysplittedtitle[1];
        clickedTitle.innerHTML=newTitle;


}
        }
```

Doing this with jquery would be much easier. Doing it with jquery-mobile would be MUCH easier. The bad thing about this code is the need to add the **onclick** event to every collapsible, including the id, which is avoidable and much simpler with jquery.

Comment: hi thanks for response i used jquery in my code to get collapsible listview as u said and i also felt that jquery is pretty easy to achieve this. I'm using <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.1.0.1.min.css"; whcih effecting my existing UI and if i remove this i'm not able to get view of collapsible listview. Is there any way to get collapsible listview without using jquery 1.0.1.css

Comment: well, since you wrote that you didn't want to use jquery i set up this pure javascript thingy... hope will be useful for someone else since it took some effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use nested listview.....

```
<h3>Nested List Example</h3>
<ul data-role="listview">
 <li>Restaurants
  <ul>
   <li>French
     <ul>
           <li>Le Central</li>
           <li>Bistro Vandome</li>
           <li>Antoine's</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Cajun and Creole
    <ul>
         <li>Bayou Bob's</li>
         <li>Pappadeaux</li>
         <li>Lucile's</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>American
    <ul>
         <li>Dixon's</li>
         <li>Vesta Dipping Grill</li>
         <li>Steuben's</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```